# UseReducer dispatch getting called twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-reducer

I have the following piece of code and the usereducer disptach method is getting called twice. I read up on this and removed the strict mode from index. Now the method is called and run properly but the UI is not getting rendered with the updated value. Can someone please help?

```
import React, { useReducer, useState } from "react";

import "../App.css";

const initialState = [
  { time: "17:00", slots: 3 },
  { time: "18:00", slots: 4 },
  { time: "19:00", slots: 2 },
  { time: "20:00", slots: 4 },
  { time: "21:00", slots: 3 },
  { time: "22:00", slots: 2 },
];

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "update": {
      let index = state.findIndex((x) => x.time === action.value);
      console.log(index);
      if (state[index].slots > 0) {
        state[index].slots -= 1;
      }
      console.log(state);
      return state;
    }
  }
};

function Reservations() {
 const [availableTimes, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
    dispatch({ type: "update", value: time });
  };

   return (
 <>
 <label htmlFor="res-time">Choose time</label>
        <select
          id="res-time "
          value={time}
          onChange={(e) => setTime(e.target.value)}
        >
          {availableTimes.map((availableTime) => {
            return (
              <option key={availableTime.time} value={availableTime.time}>
                {availableTime.time} - {availableTime.slots} slots available
              </option>
            );
          })}
        </select>

</>
  );
}

export default Reservations;
```

In my index.js, I have removed the strictmode

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  // <React.StrictMode>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
  // </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: You need to return `state` as a default case of the `switch` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React expects immutable updates. Do not directly change the state by assigning to it; instead make copies to represent the next state.

```js
return state.map(x => x.time !== action.value ? x : 
                   {...x, slots: Math.max(0, x.slots - 1)});
```